# No respond when reading Android GPS

Tags: android, android-location

I want to read GPS data from Android. I have written some code follow online tutorial

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{

private DataCollection mDataCollection;

private LocationManager mLocationManager;
private Location mLocationGPS;
private String strLocationProvider = "";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Config.mContext = this;
    mLocationManager = (LocationManager)this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    mLocationGPS = getLocationProvider(mLocationManager);
    mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 2000, 10, locationListener);
}

protected void onResume() 
{
    super.onResume();
    //  mDataCollection.register();
    mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 2000, 10, locationListener);
}

protected void onPause() 
{
    super.onPause();
    //  mDataCollection.unregister();
    mLocationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener);
}

public void startCollection(View view)
{
    //  mDataCollection.register();
}

public void stopCollection(View view)
{
    //  mDataCollection.unregister();
}

private final LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
      // Called when a new location is found by the network location provider.
        if (location != null)
        {
            double longitude = location.getLongitude();
        }
    }

    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}

    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}

    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
  };

  private Location getLocationProvider(LocationManager lm){
        Location retLocation = null ;

        Criteria mCriteria01 = new Criteria();
        mCriteria01.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
        mCriteria01.setAltitudeRequired(false);
        mCriteria01.setBearingRequired(false);
        mCriteria01.setCostAllowed(true);
        mCriteria01.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_HIGH);

        strLocationProvider = lm.getBestProvider(mCriteria01, true);
        retLocation = lm.getLastKnownLocation(strLocationProvider);

        return retLocation;
   }
}
```

When I put a break point at`double longitude = location.getLongitude();`, it never stop at that break point. I also have include the permission in manifest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.collectdata"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Could someone help me. Thanks in advance

Comment: How do you know location.getLongitude is not respond. Have you check location with log? Maybe there is trouble with breakpoint.

Comment: How to check with log. I put a break point at the location.getLongitude(); the program does not go there, when I read sensor data, the break point work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you moving at least 10 meters while testing this? That's what the "10" means in `mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 2000, 10, locationListener);`

Also, you don't need that line in both `onCreate()` and `onResume()`. Just remove it from your `onCreate()` method (though it shouldn't cause problems, just is neater).

[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestLocationUpdates(long, float, android.location.Criteria, android.app.PendingIntent)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestLocationUpdates%28long,%20float,%20android.location.Criteria,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29)

Comment: when I change the "10" to "0", also no respond

Comment: I found that location = getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER); the location is still null, but I use Network it works. Is it because I am not stand outside?

Comment: Yeah, i was thinking it was because the GPS hasn't locked on yet. That could take a couple minutes...

Comment: Maybe it is the problem, I just realize the phone keeps searching GPS. But around 10 minutes gone, it still searching...